# Google Maps API V2 marker not showing on correct position

Tags: java, android, location, google-maps-api-2, google-places

I've been following a series of tutorials to make a basic restaurant locator app for android using Google places with maps API v2. The problem I am having, is that my gps location is correct, but the marker drawn on the map to show the users location is approximately 60-65 miles south east of the users actual location.

Here is the code for my Location class:

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {
private final Context mContext;
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
boolean canGetLocation = false;
Location location = null; 
double latitude; 
double longitude; 

private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } 
        else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network Enabled");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    return longitude;
}

public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}
```

and finally here is the code for my map activity:

```
public class PlacesMapActivity extends FragmentActivity {
double latitude;
double longitude;
LatLng USER=null;
LatLng LOCATION=null;
PlacesList nearPlaces;
private GoogleMap map;
private int userIcon, locationIcon;
String address;
String name;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_places);

    userIcon = R.drawable.mark_red;
    locationIcon = R.drawable.mark_blue;

    Intent i = getIntent();

    String user_latitude = i.getStringExtra("user_latitude");
    String user_longitude = i.getStringExtra("user_longitude");
    String user_location = (user_latitude + ", " + user_longitude);

    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
    map = fm.getMap();

    USER = new LatLng((int) (Double.parseDouble(user_latitude)),
            (int) (Double.parseDouble(user_longitude)));

    Marker user = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(USER)
            .title("This is you.")
            .snippet(user_location)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(userIcon)));

    nearPlaces = (PlacesList) i.getSerializableExtra("near_places");
    if(nearPlaces != null) {
        for(Place place : nearPlaces.results) {             
            latitude = place.geometry.location.lat;
            longitude = place.geometry.location.lng;
            name = place.name;
            address= place.vicinity;
        }

        final LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

        for(int c = 0; c < nearPlaces.results.size(); c++){
            final LatLng pos = new LatLng(nearPlaces.results.get(c).geometry.location.lat,
                    nearPlaces.results.get(c).geometry.location.lng);
            builder.include(pos);
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pos)
                        .title(nearPlaces.results.get(c).name)
                        .snippet(nearPlaces.results.get(c).vicinity)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromResource(locationIcon)));
        }
    }

    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(USER, 14));

    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(9), 2000, null);
```

}

I tried to attach a screenshot, apparently I can't yet. I set the marker snippet to show the users latitude and longitude when clicked. When I click the users marker it shows the correct longitude and latitude (checked them on the internet, its within a block of my actual location), but as I stated the marker for the user always shows 60-65 miles south east. Also, the locations of the Places results are all correct and the markers in the correct locations.

any help is greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Don't convert latitude longitude to int. Use double instead and check

Comment: Wow. Works! I figured it would be something ridiculously simple. Thank you very much!

Comment: Will post it as ans :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code below

```
 USER = new LatLng((int) (Double.parseDouble(user_latitude)),
        (int) (Double.parseDouble(user_longitude)));
```

Don't convert latitude-longitude to `int`, instead keep them as `double`.

Cheers !